# Modify rootObject from within a Spring expression

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-el

Is it possible to use `SpEL` to modify the provided `rootObject` from within the expression?

Consider the following code to see what I mean:

Pojo:

```
public class Person {

    private int     age;
    private boolean mature;

    // getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

Expression:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setAge(18);

SpelParserConfiguration config = new SpelParserConfiguration(SpelCompilerMode.IMMEDIATE, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser(config);
Expression ex = parser.parseExpression("age >= 18");
boolean result = ex.getValue(person, Boolean.class);
```

See below what I want to do. Is that possible?

```
ex = parser.parseExpression("if (age >= 18) {mature = true}");
// person now has mature == true
```

**Edit:**

Instead of `SpEL` it is possible to use `javax.script`, which supports `JavaScript` and is included in the `JVM`. Here an example:

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager(); 
ScriptEngine jsEngine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

Person person = new Person();
person.setAge(18);

jsEngine.put("person", person);

jsEngine.eval("if (person.getAge() >= 18) { person.setMature(true); }");

// Calling person.isMature() in Java will now return `true`.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you would get next an exception `SpelParseException` with the next message error `After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression`.

You may do it as two next options:

### With a ternary Operator:

```
SpelParserConfiguration config = new SpelParserConfiguration(SpelCompilerMode.IMMEDIATE, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser(config);

Boolean parsedValue = parser.parseExpression("age >= 18 ? Mature=true : Mature=false").getValue(person, Boolean.class);

System.out.println(person.getMature()); // Output = true
System.out.println(parsedValue); //Output = true
```

### With two spEL expressions:

```
SpelParserConfiguration config = new SpelParserConfiguration(SpelCompilerMode.IMMEDIATE, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser(config);
Expression ex = parser.parseExpression("age >= 18");
boolean result = ex.getValue(person, Boolean.class);

if(result)
   parser.parseExpression("mature").setValue(person, "true");

System.out.println(person.getMature()); //Output = true
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It looks like SpEL is not really made for my requirements. I will probably use javax.script as I described in this blog post https://yglodt.wordpress.com/2012/03/18/scripting-in-java/